# Edit XML file using the same commands on mac, windows and linux

Tags: xml, sed

Trying to change name="Android" to name="Android1", name="Android2" and so on..

Will need to run my python script using the command line on windows, macOS and Linux.

**Output2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <robot generator="Robot 2.9 (Python 3.6.8 on linux)" generated="20190701 08:47:35.439"> 
    <suite id="s1" name="Android" source="/FILEPATHHERE">
    #ommitted unrelevant lines from xml file
```

**Problem**

I have tried a couple of ways listed on Stackoverflow but realized that it is not as easy as it seems.

Was just trying the ways using my mac terminal and when I tried running this:

```sh
sed -i 's/android/newtext' output2.xml
```

> Error: sed: 1: "output2.xml": invalid command code o

Added in `''` but another new error came up:

```sh
sed -i '' 's/android/newtext' output2.xml
```

> Error: sed: 1: "s/android/newtext": unterminated substitute in regular expression

Can I use sed commands? Seems like I am doing it wrong as I have some issues in editing XML using sed commands.

**Main References**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands
https://superuser.com/questions/916665/edit-xml-file-using-shell-script-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give an end separator for the replace pattern, btw, since you specify the `-i` flag for the backup file, it shouldn't be a zero-length extension for that, at least for macOS, check the man page about it.

```sh
sed -i 'new' 's/android/newtext/' output2.xml
```